# Could not autowired[Error: No matching bean of type]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I tried to deploy my project but I got this error and I failed to solve it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'educationUserDetailsBuilder': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.metaarchit.education.school.persistence.SemesterDao com.metaarchit.education.framework.security.spring.EducationUserDetailsBuilder.semesterDao; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.metaarchit.education.school.persistence.SemesterDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
```

I don't know what should I post on, if you need something else that you are able to provide some help, please tell me what file you need.

Comment: Damn! I didn't know using ''' ''' will not create a newline automatically

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class `SemesterDao` somewhere, right? And you probably did something like it in your code:

```
public class MyClass {
@Autowire
private SemesterDao semesterDao;
...
```

This will only work properly if Spring knows how to create an instance of it. You can achieve this by going into your class and add a annotation called `Component` on it:

```
@Component
public class SemesterDao {
}
```

Out of curiosity, when using Spring is common to use Spring Data also, this way you can extend `JpaRepository` and have many useful methods already implemented. You can take a further look on this here: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: I tried to add @Component on the SemesterDao class, but seems no use. I have some other class which function is the same as ```SemesterDao``` and with no annotation, but they can be successfully autowired. Is some of my config files' wrong?

Comment: Please let me know if you need any config file.

Comment: I forgot to say that ```SemesterDao``` is an interface class